# PowerShell Function Parameter Validation

Tags: powershell

assume I've got a Function Add-Values, how to avoid an ugly error-message, when one gives a string and not an integer for the paramters?

```
Function Add-Values
{
    param(
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)][int]$val1,
    [parameter(mandatory=$true)][int]$val2
    )

    $val1 + $val2
}
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: what do you mean by "ugly error-message" ? (can you add an example)

Comment: when I call the Function like this: Add-Values "abc" 7
I get an error:
Add-Values : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'val1'. Cannot convert value "ab" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
At line:1 char:12
+ Add-Values "ab" 7
+            ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Values], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Add-Values.
Actually I'd like to prevent such an error message.

Comment: So what should it do with "abc" and 7, instead of throwing an error?

Comment: simply saying: "wrong input" for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Janne Tuukkanen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59105355/45375) provides an effective solution.

Taking a step back:

**It's understandable to want to avoid the notoriously noisy, multi-line default error formatting** in *Windows PowerShell* and *PowerShell [Core] 6.x* versions, which can be confusing to end users.

**Two - suboptimal - options** are:

- Use `$host.UI.WriteErrorLine($errMsg)`, which prints just the content of `$errMsg` in red, without any additional information.
- Another option is to use `Write-Warning $errMsg`, which prints the message in yellow, but prefixes it with `WARNING:`.

**In general, though, it is best *not* to bypass the usual error reporting features** (for consistency and to support further programmatic processing), which PowerShell [Core] 7+ can help with:

**PowerShell [Core] 7+** now defaults to ***concise* error formatting**, via the `ConciseView` view that was introduced in 7.0:

**With preference variable `$ErrorView` set to the new default, `ConciseView`**, your command would fail as follows if given a non-integer (prints on a single line, in red; spread across multiple lines here for readability):

```
Add-Values: Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'val1'. 
Cannot convert value "abc" to type "System.Int32". 
Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

Screen shot (custom background color):

[image]

While certainly an improvement over the old formatting, it is still somewhat wordy.

However, you can **perform *custom validation* on parameters** via the `[ValidateScript()]` attribute, which in PowerShell v6+ also supports an `ErrorMessage` property, so you could do the following:

```
Function Add-Values
{
  param(
    [ValidateScript({ ($_ -as [int]) -is [int] }, ErrorMessage='Please pass an integer.')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    $val1
    ,
    [ValidateScript({ ($_ -as [int]) -is [int] }, ErrorMessage='Please pass an integer.')]
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    $val2
  )

  $val1 + $val2
}
```

Note:

- The `[ValidateScript()]` attribute accepts a script block inside of which the value passed by the user is reflected in the automatic `$_` variable. The script block must output a Boolean that indicates whether the value is valid - (effectively) `$true`) - or not - (effectively) `$false`.
- Only script-block *literals* (`{ ... }`) and (non-expandable) string literals are supported inside `[ValidateScript()]`, so the values must be repeated for the two parameters.
- `($_ -as [int]) -is [int]` uses the `-as` operator to see if the given parameter value (`$_`) is already an `[int]` or can be converted to one, and returns an `[int]` instance if so, and `$null` otherwise. `-is [int]` then tests if the `-as` operation indeed returned an integer or not.

With invalid arguments - e.g., `Add-Values abc 2` - you'll then get something like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just leave the type undefined in the parameter declaration, and check them in the function code:

```
function Foo {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory)]$a,
        [parameter(Mandatory)]$b
    )

    if($a -is [int] -and $b -is [int]) {
        return $a + $b
    }

    Write-Output "Bad parameters"
}
```

Comment: I appreciate it, Janne (+1). Please also consider replacing `Write-Output` with something like `$host.ui.WriteErrorLine('Bad parameters')` (`Write-Error` is _conceptually_ appropriate, but avoiding the "noise" it generates is what prompted the question to begin with).